# This webpage has a redirect loop in spring-security application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

i have a web application in spring which uses spring security, when i try to excute the application it says

```
This webpage has a redirect loop
```

this is my `security-context.xml` after adding this only i get this exception

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<b:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- HTTP security configurations -->
    <http use-expressions="true">
        <form-login login-processing-url="/resources/j_spring_security_check"
            login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t" />
        <logout logout-url="/resources/j_spring_security_logout" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll()" />

    </http>

    <!-- Configure Authentication mechanism -->
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="RIGHT_LIST,RIGHT_CANCEL,RIGHT_CREATE,RIGHT_UPDATE" />
                <user name="antony" password="antony" authorities="RIGHT_LIST,RIGHT_CANCEL,RIGHT_CREATE,RIGHT_UPDATE" />
                <user name="rod" password="rod" authorities="RIGHT_LIST,RIGHT_CREATE"/>
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled">
        <expression-handler ref="expHandler"/>
    </global-method-security>

    <b:bean id="expHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
        <b:property name="permissionEvaluator">
            <b:bean  class="com.anto.springsec.security.CreateContactPermissionEvaluator"/>
        </b:property>
    </b:bean>

</b:beans>
```

i have  one login.jsp and one more createContact.jsp

this is my home controler :

```
package com.anto.springsec.controllers;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

        return "login";
    }

}
```

please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe the order of `intercept-url` is important here, and it seems like your `/**` pattern is swallowing `/login` and `/resources` too.

Try this:-

```
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/login" security="none"/>

<http use-expressions="true">
    <form-login login-processing-url="/resources/j_spring_security_check"
        login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t" />
    <logout logout-url="/resources/j_spring_security_logout" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</http>
```

This configuration is very similar to one of my existing projects.

**UPDATE**

This is the configuration I'm currently using in my project:-

```
<security:http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
<security:http pattern="/login" security="none"/>
<security:http pattern="/error/**" security="none"/>

<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:form-login login-page="/login"
                         authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=1"
                         default-target-url="/"
                         always-use-default-target="true"/>
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
</security:http>
```

**03-19-13**

In order to use `security` attribute in `http` tag, you will need Spring Security 3.1... see http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#new-3.1-ns

Comment: i get exception when i use your configuration settings

Comment: I updated my post above with my actual configuration from my project.

Comment: Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'security' is not allowed to appear in element 'http'.
 - cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'http'. One of

Comment: It seems like you are using Spring Security 3.0, I'm using 3.1 if that makes a difference.

Comment: It's definitely a 3.1 thing, see section 3.2.3 at http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html ... my configuration is valid.

Comment: not sure, but i am using `<spring-security.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</spring-security.version>`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26417/discussion-between-anto-and-limc)

Comment: This is not a good idea, because <http pattern="/login" security="none">  totally turns off all security checks on that url, and you can't use spring's built-in CSRF protection here since CSRF token will not be generated.
The author has only little error with expression in <http> config: "permitAll" expression must not have parentheses

Answer (score 2):

Try this

change

`<intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll()" />`

to

```
<intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
```

**OR**

```
<intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="isAnonymous()" />
```

As you have expression true I think you have to use isAnonymous()

[See docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html)

intercept-url element to say that any requests for the login page should be available to anonymous users. Otherwise the request would be matched by the pattern /** and it wouldn't be possible to access the login page itself! This is a common configuration error and will result in an infinite loop in the application. [Read more from here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html)